# Can we run two process task in parallel container, like 350 files in first thread and rest in the second

Tags: powershell, ssis

i am using the powershell script to compress the files.here i need to zip the files  parallel'y in sequence container.350 files in one container and remaining in another.How can i split.

**In execute process task i just executing the ps script. Here I just filtered the .txt file and inside the foreach loop zipping process is done.**

Here how can I zip 350 files in one container and remaining in another container?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $srcdir -Filter *.txt | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).Date}
foreach($file in $files) {
}
```

Comment: Research `Powershell Runspaces`. Should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Runspaces mentioned by @Sid will offer the best performance option.

Powershell jobs may be sufficent for what you wish to accomplish as well:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $srcdir -Filter *.txt | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).Date}
$Job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    foreach($file in $files[0..349]) {
    }
}

$Job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    foreach($file in $files[350..$files.length]) {
    }
}

Wait-Job $Job1, $Job2
Receive-Job $Job1, $Job2
```

- Wait-Job = Wait for both Jobs to finish.
- Receive-Job = Gather any outputs from Jobs.